# BUILD_STATUS on jenkins does not print the value

Tags: jenkins

We've got Jenkins on both SITE_A and SITE_C

On SITE_A once job is done it prints $BUILD_NUMBER and $BUILD_STATUS correctly

However, on SITE_C $BUILD_NUMBER is printed but "$BUILD_STATUS" is getting printed as "$BUILD_STATUS"

We have verified the 'Installed plug-ins' between SITE_A and SITE_C but we could not figure out any difference

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are the build-steps printing the command exactly the same? Is it a shell step or what is it? In shell, echoing a unset env-variable should give you an empty string. This seems to be a coding fault...

Comment: Jenkins masters are same version?

Answer (score 0):

After installing the plug-ins we just 'restarted' Jenkins which fixed the issue